# JavaScript: Need lower div (under absolute div) NOT to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an issue with the layout of my website right now...

The layout is similar to this fiddle I made. Top layer has my project thumbnails, and the lower layer gets exposed to show project details when user clicks a thumbnail.

Problem I am having is that a user has to scroll down to click a thumbnail on the top layer. Then, when the layer fades out, the lower div has already scrolled with it - and I need the div to be scrollTop(0) instead...

Please see my fiddle to understand what I am talking about:

```js
$('#click').on('click', function(){
 $('#topPanel').fadeOut(600);
})
```

```css
#click {
  padding:10px 15px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:100;
}

#topPanel, #bottomPanel {
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
#topPanel {
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
}
#bottomPanel {
  background:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}
#topPanel p, #bottomPanel p {
  padding: 500px 0;
  text-transformation:uppercase;
}
#bottomPanel p:nth-child(odd){
  background:#555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">CLICK ME TO FADEOUT TOP</button>
<br>
<p>please scroll down and then click button above to see issue</p>

<div id="topPanel">
  <p>top of page</p>
  <p>middle of page</p>
  <p>bottom of page</p>
</div>

<div id="bottomPanel">
  <p>top of page</p>
  <p>middle of page</p>
  <p>bottom of page</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/reese329/50urkgtm/

Comment: you can SEE what I am talking about here on my site:   [WEBSITE LINK](http://www.reeseholtze.com/portfolio) , it's hard to explain so I thought that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your panels aren't scrolling: the whole document is scrolling! The trick is to set `overflow: hidden` on a wrapper element (or the body), and make the panels themselves scrollable with `overflow-y: scroll`. [Here is a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/50urkgtm/1/)

Notice that I had to set the height of the panels explicitly (to `100vh`, filling the viewport).

I also fixed your `text-transform: uppercase` rule (the style is `text-transform`, not `text-transformation` :) ).

Comment: Apparently it won't count my like (I am still new), but I do not know how to thank you enough!!! Duh, that completely makes sense... It doesn't quite work on my actual site, but I am sure it's because I messed too many things up trying to fix it. Thank's again! @this-vidor!

Comment: @ReeseHoltze Glad this solution (almost) works for you! There should be a check-mark under the up/down arrows that allows you to "accept" an answer. Is the bug you are still experiencing related to your original question?

Comment: I got it to work on my site too now! You're awesome, thanks a million!